# Forward inputnames in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use `inputname` through a stack of function calls that basically forward input arguments using `varargin`. It looks like this:

```
function called_function( varargin )
    other_function(varargin{:});
end

function other_function( varargin )
    for i = 1:nargin
        inputname(i)
    end
end
```

The problem is, Matlab doesn't seem to like this. For example:

```
>> x=1; y=2; called_function(x,y)

ans =

     ''

ans =

     ''
```

returns two empty strings when I would expect `'x'` and `'y'`.

I know the obvious solution is to extract input-names at the first level and forward that to all nested levels, but it's ugly. Is there a way to forward input names in Matlab?

Comment: The right solution is probably not to use input names. Why do you think you have to use them?

Comment: Writing a thin wrapper for `save`, most of the time I'd like to save variables with the names they have. But it's a matter of comfort, I could always specify the names manually of course, as if I were defining a structure.

Comment: Use save with the struct option and convert everything from individual variables to a struct on the first level.

Comment: That's what I did originally, then I tried to generalise that a bit deeper. I guess I shouldn't have :)

Comment: If you see any limitations with the struct solution feel free to ask a new question about that, I am sure it can be solved better than messing with inputnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned in the comments, it is probably best that you use a different method, but if you want to, you need to pass the names in a separate argument:

```
function called_function( varargin )
    argnames = arrayfun(@inputname, 1:nargin, 'uni', 0);
    other_function(varargin, argnames);
end

function other_function( argvals, argnames )
    for i = 1:numel(argnames)
        argnames{i}
    end
end
```